# How to merge pandas series off of a column of dates

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two series:

```
        date     DEF
0  1/31/1986  0.0140
1  2/28/1986  0.0150
2  3/31/1986  0.0160
3  4/30/1986  0.0120
4  5/30/1986  0.0120
        date     PE
0  1/31/1900  12.71
1  2/28/1900  12.94
2  3/31/1900  13.04
3  4/30/1900  13.21
4  5/31/1900  12.58
```

I need to iterate over several DataFrames of this nature and combine them all into one big DataFrame, where only values that align with the dates get added. My function so far:

```
def get_combined_vars(start, end):
rows = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end, freq='BM')
df1 = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['date'])
for key in variables.keys():
    check = variables[key][0]
    if check == 1:
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(variables[key][1]())
        print(df2.head(5))
        pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(datekey=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d') + '-1900')),
          df2, 
          right_on='date', 
          left_on='datekey',
          direction='nearest',
          suffixes=('_x',''))
        print(df1.head(10))
return df1
```

I can't seem to find the right command to merge DataFrames based off of a column.

Desired output:

```
        date     DEF       PE
0  1/31/1900  0.0140    12.71
1  2/28/1900  0.0150    12.94
2  3/31/1900  0.0160    13.04
3  4/30/1900  0.0120    13.21
4  5/31/1900  0.0120    12.58
```

Merge_asof issue:

```
runfile('H:/Market Timing/Files/market_timing.py', wdir='H:/Market Timing/Files')
        date    BY
0  1/31/1963  0.98
1  2/28/1963     1
2  3/29/1963  1.01
3  4/30/1963  1.01
4  5/31/1963  1.01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 303, in _convert_listlike
    values, tz = tslib.datetime_to_datetime64(arg)
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 1884, in pandas._libs.tslib.datetime_to_datetime64
TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "H:/Market Timing/Files/market_timing.py", line 88, in <module>
    print(get_combined_vars('1/31/1995', '1/31/2005').head(10))
  File "H:/Market Timing/Files/market_timing.py", line 43, in get_combined_vars
    pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(datekey=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d') + '-1900')),
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 373, in to_datetime
    values = _convert_listlike(arg._values, True, format)
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 306, in _convert_listlike
    raise e
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\datetimes.py", line 294, in _convert_listlike
    require_iso8601=require_iso8601
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2156, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2379, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 2373, in pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\parsing.pyx", line 99, in pandas._libs.tslibs.parsing.parse_datetime_string
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 1182, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Developer\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 581, in parse
    ret = default.replace(**repl)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

I believe on the third pass of these two DataFrames attempting to be combined it runs into this error: ValueError: day is out of range for month

Can a buffer be added for discrepancies in data like this?

Comment: What is your expected results?  Does row with index 4 successfully join?  First data frame 5/30 second dataframe 5/31.

Comment: Ah, I'll add expected results. I was hoping to add some kind of "buffer" to account for several days of difference on the dates (these are market values and sometimes they are reported late/early)

Comment: Was a mistake on my end, didn't notice I used a different DF for the output - fixed

Comment: I think your 'day is out of range for month' is bad data.  You do the casting to datetime inside of `merge_asof`  Do the cast before, so you can verify that you have good data.  It seems like to me you are maybe trying to create a end of month day like April 31 or February 29 on non-leap years.

Comment: I managed to handle that simply by offsetting every date to the respective month's end date, but now I get this issute :pandas.errors.MergeError: incompatible merge keys [0] object and datetime64[ns], must be the same type, and I specifically pd.to_datetime every date in every DF, so I'm not sure why this is popping up. I also use .dropna() to get rid of the NaNs

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.merge_asof`, however, first you'll need to get your dates on a common year.

```
pd.merge_asof(df1.assign(datekey=pd.to_datetime(df1['date'].dt.strftime('%m-%d') + '-1900')),
              df2, 
              right_on='date', 
              left_on='datekey',
              direction='nearest',
              suffixes=('_x',''))[['date','DEF','PE']]
```

Output:

```
        date    DEF     PE
0 1900-01-31  0.014  12.71
1 1900-02-28  0.015  12.94
2 1900-03-31  0.016  13.04
3 1900-04-30  0.012  13.21
4 1900-05-31  0.012  12.58
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that `merge_asof` existed.

Comment: @PhilSheard Thank you! It is a handy function.

Comment: KeyError "Date" means that you have no column heading with 'Date' check for whitespace.  Sometimes you have columns names 'Date ' and you don't see the space when looking at dataframes.  A quick way to eliminate this problem is to `df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()`. You can do something like this to see whitespaces in column headings: `df.head().to_dict()`.

Comment: Updated post with a followup question, how would I convert every date to the end of every business month?

Comment: @Muffinman what do you mean about "third pass" - are you trying to merge the same data multiple times? Can you indicate which row of data is causing the Value error?

Comment: I'm not sure which row because I don't know how to place a check in the middle of the merge_asof function, however if you look at the updated function in my post it shows the exact error, which occurs with the first two DF's being merged. By third pass I meant third row, because as you can see the dates are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You would use `pandas.Merge` (or `DataFrame.join` as shorthand) to do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Merge(df1, df2, on="date")
```

...But as Scott Boston mentioned in his comment, the data doesn't align so you won't get your expected results.